# Change .NetCore 3.1 to .NetFramework4.7

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-framework-version

Can I change the target framework from .netcore 3.1 to .netFramework 4.7. If I can then how can I do this?

Comment: I guess my answer is where you looking for, but of not, please add more details and some relative code/config

Answer (score 2):

Chance the target framework to `net47` (or `net472`, recommend) in your csproj file.

For example:

From:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>   
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

To:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>   
    <TargetFramework>net47</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

See [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks) (shows all possible options)

Comment: Basically I made a project in .netcore3.1 and also added the UnitTest project in it but even after adding the reference of my console project to my Test Project its not taking the classes of my console project. So I thought may be its due to Target Framework but still its not working.

Comment: I guess that should be another question, otherwise things got mixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change the version with two simple changes,

Change the SDK version in global.json

```
{
  "sdk": {
-    "version": "3.1.200"
+    "version": "5.0.100"
  }
}
```

Update the target framework :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

      <PropertyGroup>
    -    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    +    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
      </PropertyGroup>
    
    </Project>
```

you can also see microsoft's article for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio